# How to get variable name from DbgDeclareInst LLVM IR?

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to get the variable name from DbgDeclareInst type Instruction in LLVM IR.

Showing Snippet of LLVM IR code.

```
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %i, metadata !11, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !12
```

I want to get variable information like `%i` about the source code `int i`

Corresponding LLVM IR:

```
%i = alloca i32, align 4
```

I am able to extract `i32* %i` but not `%i` from the IR.
I believe MetaDataAsValue may come useful but unable to get the exact solution

Comment: From the `llvm.dbg.declare` you should be able to go to the corresponding `MDNode`. Then if its a `DILocalVariable` you should be able to just do `getName()`

Comment: Thanks @qbit for the solution.. used the same steps but forgot to mention the solution earlier